# Is there any useful application area of uric acid in a desert climate?

Tags: fertilizer

My grandfather has a lot of bird feces. We are planning to take uric acid out of those feces and plan to use it if there is a good application. The climate around us is desert and we would like to know what we can do with this uric acid. We would like to use waste for some useful applications for planting.

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! Why not simply compost the bird droppings, perhaps along with any other compostables you might have? If you do hot composting you will probably kill a lot of pathogens and reduce the risk of diseases like avian flu.

Comment: Hi, Thank you! :) It is a very good idea indeed. I can use your suggested hot composting method but I also would like to know whether I can do something with uric acid or not. If yes, I also want to use it and not waste it.

Answer (score 2):

Urea (Ammonia) can be used for scrubbing sulphur oxides & Nitrogen oxides, to create the fertilizer compounds: Ammonium Sulphate & Ammonium Nitrate.

For more info, see: [Is there any way to recycle air-pollution into fertilizer?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/6318/is-there-any-way-to-recycle-air-pollution-into-fertilizer/)